# How does dgrouter handle middlewares?

Tags: go, discord

I have a question regarding middlewares in various places:

1. I was reading about using middlewares with just stdlib to write request handlers as mentioned here: (https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware)

```
func middlewareOne(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Our middleware logic goes here...
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/", middlewareOne(middlewareTwo(finalHandler)))
```

It makes sense to me that passing one handler inside another in this format executes the next middleware's ServeHTTP

2. I am using dgrouter for discord command routing and I found that I could use middlewares in there as well as defined in this example:
   https://github.com/Necroforger/dgrouter/blob/master/examples/middleware/middleware.go#L40-L59

The method used to register middlewares is defined like so:
https://github.com/Necroforger/dgrouter/blob/master/exrouter/router_wrapper.go#L41-L49

My question is why is the middleware not called like how it is done in `net/http` and just the function name is passed:

```
router.Group(func(r *exrouter.Route) {
        // Added routes inherit their parent category.
        // I set the parent category here and it won't affect the
        // Actual router, just this group
        r.Cat("main")

        // This authentication middleware applies only to this group
        r.Use(Auth)
        log.Printf("len(middleware) = %d\n", len(r.Middleware))

        r.On("testauth", func(ctx *exrouter.Context) {
            ctx.Reply("Hello " + ctx.Get("member").(*discordgo.Member).Nick + ", you have permission to use this command")
        })
    })
```

> r.Use(Auth)

Is what i have difficulty understanding. Why is the function not being called?

Comment: It just binds the function. It’s a closure which will be called by the framework when the route will be triggered.

Comment: @oren Do you mean that the framework "dgrouter" passes in the appropriate argument here: https://github.com/Necroforger/dgrouter/blob/master/examples/middleware/middleware.go#L40

Comment: Yep, at line 52: ‘fn(ctx)’. But notice that ‘Auth’ also returns a function, which isn’t called right away, but only when the router will be triggered.

Comment: @oren thank you :). Can you write an answer for it so i can mark it answered?